# Simplifying $\gcd\left(n_2,\text{digitreverse}\left(n_2\right)\right)$ for binary numbers $n_2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

Well, I am trying to find a general formula for the following statement.

> Simplify the formula stated below, where the $\gcd$ is taken of a binary number $n_2$ and its digit resverse in binary.

Mathematically speaking:

$$f(n_2):=\gcd\left(n_2,\text{digitreverse}\left(n_2\right)\right)\tag1$$

**EDIT:**
I am a student in computer science and I am trying to do this operation for very large values of n10 which makes it impossible to it case by case. I am trying to compute this up to $n_{10}=10^{35}$.

---

Examples:

- When $n_{10}=12345$, we get $n_2=11000000111001$ and $\text{digitreverse}\left(11000000111001\right)=10011100000011$:
  $$f(11000000111001)=\gcd\left(11000000111001,10011100000011\right)=33\tag2$$
- When $n_{10}=54321$, we get $n_2=1101010000110001$ and $\text{digitreverse}\left(1101010000110001\right)=1000110000101011$:
  $$f(1101010000110001)=\gcd\left(1101010000110001,1000110000101011\right)=1\tag3$$

Comment: What is the source of this question?  Is there any reason to imagine that it has a pleasant closed form answer?

Comment: I note that $33$ does not divide $12345$

Comment: @lulu I am a student in computer science and I am trying to do this operation for very large values of $n_{10}$ which makes it impossible to it case by case.

Comment: @lulu that is correct. But I take the GCD of two binary numbers treated like they're in base 10. So you will get 33 for formula $(2)$.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to mention that.

Comment: Is "digitreverse" defined for even numbers?

Comment: If this truly has no context behind it, then I'd be skeptical that a simple closed form would exist.  In any case, I suggest computing your function for lots of values $n$ and checking to see if any patterns emerge.

Comment: How many large values of $n$? For what purpose? Is it really too computationally expensive to just have the program do the Euclidean algo?

Comment: So you're not actually talking about binary numbers at all, but rather decimal numbers that happen to contain only the digits 0 and 1, correct?